# Why location service background not working if call LocationManager by Button_Action swift

Tags: swift, background-process, locationmanager

## I'm have doubt about background service of location if we call location manager in viewDidload we can manage call location when app will terminate by we know location running by push notification message

I'm set `info.plist` done , import all I think is use location and notificationcenter done.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    locationManager.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = true
    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters
    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
}

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
     if(!gpsEnable) {
         print("update disable")
         return
     }
     print("update enable")
     for location in locations {
         processLocation(location)
     }
 }
```

## But if call by Button it's not working when app will terminate

```
@IBAction func location(_ sender: Any) {
    locationManager.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = true
    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters
    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
}
```

## I expect to know that the reason to work cannot be called location same the working of ViewDidload.

## I don't speak English very well thank you.

Answer (score 0):

## UPDATE

## I know process why not working when not call in viewDidload if app will terminate

if you ever did project about keep data log of location when app will terminate then location it's will running location update when you move til location current of you change and call method of LocationUpdate or CLVisit or CLLocationChange and another you know that in your project.

ok .

## First

You should call this in your somewhere view controller in project:

override func viewDidLoad() {

```
super.viewDidLoad()
locationManager.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = true
locationManager.delegate = self
locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters
locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
```

}

if you not call this location manager(location update) it's will be not work when you kill app.

Regular when kill app we must move for location change position then in your project location begin work process locationUpdate or if you want to know now you can turn on again in privacy Location

[image]

## Second

condition location update if app will terminate when function must be call use in ViewDidLoad in first ViewController only.

if you ask me why it's work first ViewController only.

I will answer "I don't know ,but we test for process in my app test til know process run specifically in first ViewController in ViewDidLoad, ViewWillAppear,ViewDidAppear ".

look in image this:
[image]

## RootView ,SecondView

we test process by look in root view ,yes it's first view when I call location manager in view

override func viewDidLoad() {

```
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
     locationManager.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = true
       locationManager.delegate = self
     locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters
   locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
   NotificationStatic.shared.showNotification(title:"viewDidload01",body:"did load",identifierRequest : "view1")
```

}

when process come in viewDidload process will can run process in location update when app will terminate

## But you call location manager in SecondView but in RootView not call location it's will be work !!

if you ever perform to SecondView then in SecondView -> run ViewDidload (have location manager) then kill app then open location service again.it's work cause you ever call use method of location manager ,but it's can't get location log because in RootView(first view controller) haven't function about location update in viewDidload

## conclude

## in process of location service background it's will be work only in ViewDidload, ViewWillAppear, ViewDidAppear process in first view controller of app

## I'm newbie skill for describe and newbie talk English thank you.